# How to combine the results of two queries into a single dataset (one above the other) and still display the titles of the table below

Tags: mysql, sql, union

This is the query I tried (it's simplified and doesn't include joins). It lets me display one table below the other but it doesn't show the column titles for the one below.

`SELECT column1, column2
FROM Table1
UNION
SELECT column2, column3
FROM Table2`

I'm getting the following output

```
column1 | column2
  val1      val2
  val3      val4
```

The output I need for my project is:

```
column1 | column2
  val1      val2

column3 | column4
  val3      val4
```

It would be extremely helpful if anyone knew how to display it in this way! :)

Comment: A SQL query returns one set of columns, with specified types and names.  A single query cannot return rows with different column names.

Answer (score 1):

One query can only return a specified set of columns.  If you want all four columns, then you need four columns in the result set:

```
SELECT column1, column2, NULL as column3, NULL as column4
FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, NULL, column3, column4
FROM Table2;
```